# Replacing the contents of one archive with another of the same name?

Tags: java, io, zip

I'm facing a situation where I have two archives that have the same name but are located in different directories (of course). Using the new [Zip File System Provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html), I have created an evironment in which I can use file operations on each of the zip files. The problem however lies in the fact that I can't manage to create a `Path` for either of the files - because `filesystem.getPath(pathtoFile)` returns the same value for both archives.

Essentially what I'm looking for is a way for `root\archive.zip\folder\file.txt` to be valid.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where the problem is you're facing, but I just released a new version of the SoftSmithy Utility Library, which comes with some utility classes for NIO File. It especially simplifies copying files across file systems.

The library is Open Source and it might help to get you started.

Here is the tutorial:
http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/0.2/docs/tutorial/nio-file/index.html

You can download the library from here:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/softsmithy/files/softsmithy/v0.2/

Or with Maven:

```
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.softsmithy.lib</groupId>  
    <artifactId>softsmithy-lib-core</artifactId>  
    <version>0.2</version>   
</dependency>
```

Note: an URI to a resource in a JAR/ ZIP file had the form:

```
jar:<jarURIPart>!/<resource entry>
```